# .Net adding a prefix ctl00_CPHPageContents_ to control IDs

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, clientid

I have an asp.net C# web forms application in .net framework 4
In my pages, when I view html source it changes control IDs to something like `ctl00_CPHPageContents_txtUserID` actually it is `txtUserID`

This application was first in Framework 3.5 and IDs were generated like `CPHPageContents_txtUserID`

So, in short, in Framework 3.5 Id was `CPHPageContents_txtUserID` and now in Framework 4 ID is `ctl00_CPHPageContents_txtUserID` which is breaking our automation tests. Can I remove this `ctl00` added by Framework 4?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Forcing client ids in ASP.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/546392/forcing-client-ids-in-asp-net)

Comment: @Rowland Shaw, Its different question than the one you are referring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution here http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/03/30/cleaner-html-markup-with-asp-net-4-web-forms-client-ids-vs-2010-and-net-4-0-series.aspx

Setting ClientIDMode to Predictable removes ct100_ prefix.

Answer (score 2):

Check the [ClientIDMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientidmode.aspx) of your page; this was a new feature in .NET 4 that gives you a bit more control over the IDs generated by web forms.  Although if it's adding a ctl100_ in front that implies there's a new server side control wrapping CPHPageContents that didn't before.

Comment: yes I know about ClientIDMode but I don't want to change it now as it will break our automation tests. But I don't think we added any control which is wrapping CPHPageContents. then from where "ctl00" might be coming?

Comment: Either a change in the way the control IDs are generated happened or their is a new server side control in the hierarchy that wasn't there before.  If you are using master pages have you checked that there is an additional control in the hierarchy.  You could also set a debug point and find the control with the id of 'ctl100' and see what it is (assuming it exists on the page).

Comment: Just figured out its added by .net if ClientModeId is set to AutoID.

Answer (score 0):

ClientIDMode is the best approach.  If you set it to 'static' the Id's for the controls in your page will be the ones you set.   But if you are maintaining an old project and have to stick with an older version of the framework for whatever reason, you can add the following to your page:

```
<asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="aspPrefix" />
<div id="idPrefix" style="display:none" ><%= aspPrefix.ClientID %></div>
```

Then, from javascript you add:

```
var hiddenFieldId = $('#idPrefix').text();
ver controlPrefix = hiddenFieldId.substr(0, hiddenFieldId.length - 9);  // 9 chars in 'aspPrefix'
```

With the prefix you can now get the id's for the other controls in your page.